# Android layout crash: Binary XML file line #10 must supply a layout width

Tags: android, exception, layout, resources, crash

I'm stumped, I've already deduced it to being within this merge section of the larger layout (*edit* thanks, yes line #10 was sort of obvious, the textview on line 10 clearly needed the width and height, but there were no crashes using just textview that exists further in the code, which I had pasted into line #10)

```
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/frameLayoutLatest">
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/subLinLayoutHeader" android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageView android:src="@drawable/layouttriangle" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"></ImageView>
</LinearLayout>
<TableLayout android:id="@+id/subLinLayout" android:layout_below="@id/subLinLayoutHeader" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"> 
    <TableRow  android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="vertical">
            <ScrollView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <!-- list view goes here -->
                <TextView android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" android:text="Dummy text" android:textColor="#ffffff" android:textSize="16dip"></TextView>
            </ScrollView>
        </LinearLayout>
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <TableLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <TableRow android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <TextView android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" android:text="Latest Articles" android:textColor="#ffffff" android:textSize="16dip"></TextView>
                </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>
        <ScrollView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
         <!--  list view goes here -->
        </ScrollView>
        </LinearLayout>

</TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Where's waldo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On line 10 of course :)
Your code doesn't supply a layout_height or a layout_width for the TextView.  Both are required for every xml element.

This is your code:

```
<TextView
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
android:text="Dummy text"
android:textColor="#ffffff"
android:textSize="16dip">
</TextView>
```

Try this instead (or use match_parent instead of wrap_content)

```
<TextView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
android:text="Dummy text"
android:textColor="#ffffff"
android:textSize="16dip">
</TextView>
```

**EDIT to explain second TextView's behavior**

Well, I learned something new today.
According to the TableRow documentation,

```
The children of a TableRow do not need to specify the layout_width
and layout_height attributes in the XML file. TableRow always enforces
those values to be respectively MATCH_PARENT and WRAP_CONTENT.
```

That's why it didn't throw an error.

Comment: Then why doesn't it crash using the other exact same textview further in the document? I had copied that one to the place up above. It would be obvious if the layout crashing or xml error reporting was consistent to all xml errors.. but it isn't.

Comment: I assume that it would, it just crashes at line 10 first.  Are you saying that if you add layout_width and layout_height attributes to the first TextView but not the second everything works?

Comment: that is what I am saying yes. the layout will render on actual devices with no problem.  no XML builder errors, no crashes etc. I didn't think it cared about width height on textview that why I was stumped

Comment: Then I sincerely doubt that the second TextView is ever displayed on screen.  If it was, it would produce an error like the one you saw before.  From the documentation on layouts ["All view groups include a width and height (layout_width and layout_height), and each view is required to define them"](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html).  I guess you could have declared them programmatically, but Android will refuse to draw a view unless you set a width and height, one way or another.

Comment: Don't know how to prove it to you, but comment out the first textview and run that block of code. It shows "Latest Articles", logcat doesn't even show an error, perhaps I can get ranked up.

Comment: Well color me surprised.  I tested it and you're right.  TableRows are a special case.  I added the explanation to my original answer as an edit for future reference.

Answer (score 2):

Your TextView in the ScrollView of line 10 of this file requires a layout_height and layout_width attribute so the system will know the dimensions you would like your TextView to be.  If you're not sure where to start just copy the two attributes from the ScrollView that contains it.

Comment: Then why doesn't it crash using the other exact same textview further in the document? I had copied that one to the place up above. It would be obvious if the layout crashing or xml error reporting was consistent to all xml errors.. but it isn't.

Comment: No, I mean this code section works if I take that textview out and leave the other also incorrect one there. You can try it yourself. Logcat doesn't even show an error and the app works fine.

Comment: Its in a table row, which handles layout differently.

Answer (score 1):

Isn’t the error message clear enough? Something is missing a layout width (the two `TextView`), your problem will probably be fixed if you fix this.

Comment: Then why doesn't it crash using the other exact same textview further in the document? I had copied that one to the place up above. It would be obvious if the layout crashing or xml error reporting was consistent to all xml errors.. but it isn't.

Comment: First add the `layout:width` and `layout:height` in your code, and then come back if it still doesn’t work.

Comment: it worked. I am still curious why it ignored the layout error on the other textview and was working and rendering fine